# Simple method of counting non-NAs in column of data String

Tags: r, na

I am trying to find a simple way of counting the non missing cases in a column of a data frame. I have used the function:

```
foo<- function(x) { sum(!is.na(x)) }
```

and then apply it to a data frame via sapply()

```
stats$count <- sapply(OldExaminee, foo2, simplify=T)
```

Although this is working fine, I am just in disbelieve that there isn't a simpler way of counting, i.e. something in the base set of function.

Any ideas?

Comment: welcome to SO  `sapply` is in `base`.. and `sapply( yourdata , function( x ) sum( !is.na( x ) ) )` is pretty quick. :)

Comment: @AnthonyDamico thanks, I have used this page many times and finally decided to join. I am a loyal R user but I can't believe that there isn't a truly simple function for count.

Comment: @SprengMeister, since your intended use is on a `data.frame`, you can use `colSums` with `is.na`. Check my answer.

Comment: @Arun yours is the most simple one yet. Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For a `data.frame` you can get it using `colSums` and `is.na`:

```
set.seed(45)
df <- data.frame(matrix(sample(c(NA,1:5), 50, replace=TRUE), ncol=5))
#    X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
# 1   3  2 NA  2 NA
# 2   1  5  1  1  4
# 3   1  1  3  2  3
# 4   2  2  3  5  3
# 5   2  2  5  2  2
# 6   1  2 NA  3  3
# 7   1  5  5  5  2
# 8   3 NA  4  1  5
# 9   1  2  3 NA  1
# 10 NA  1  1  2  2

colSums(!is.na(df))
# X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 
#  9  9  8  9  9
```

Answer (score 10):

you could use na.omit

```
length(na.omit(x));
```

along with apply as the post by caelorus indicates

Comment: this is indeed simpler, but as I said to caerolus, not a "build in" function. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: @SprengMeister the `table` function exlcudes `NA`, so you might say `sum(table(x))` is a little closer to 'built in'. But I suspect @AdityaSihag's answer is faster for large data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `which` and `length`:

```
length(which(!is.na(x$col)))
```

`which` returns the indexes of the matching elements (in this case, the non-`NA`s), and `length` tells you how many of those indexes there are.

For all columns at once:

```
apply(OldExaminee, 2, function(x){ length(which(!is.na(x))) })
```

Comment: Thanks for your idea. It confirms that there probably is not completely simple solutions, something along the lines of `count(df$x, NA)`.

Comment: That I didn't know. Thank you!