# Aggregate by group and get count, mean and sd of non-NA values for different data.frame columns

Tags: r, aggregate, missing-data

I am having some difficulty counting non-missing values by group through the function below (which also gives sd, and mean):

```
test <- do.call(data.frame, aggregate(. ~ treatment, have, function(x) c(n = sum(!is.na(x)), mean = mean(x), sd = sd(x))))
```

It ends up giving me the number of non-missing for all columns in the dataframe instead of just a single column.

I have been looking through SO for some advice and found  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15704665/simple-method-of-counting-non-nas-in-column-of-data-string), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986101/counting-non-nas-in-a-data-frame-getting-answer-as-a-vector), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41853387/count-non-na-numbers-in-a-column-and-output-a-data-frame) helpful, but I can't figure out why the aggregate with the function(x) would combine some columns for the sum(!is.na(x), but not for the mean or sd.

EDIT: Adding tables

[This is the data I have](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0yzz83kpo15hbg4/have.txt?dl=0)

[This is the data I get from my code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/izdaa9428485nrb/get.txt?dl=0)

[This is the table I want](https://www.dropbox.com/s/09hhm5l8ssexeny/want.xlsx?dl=0)

You will notice in the 'have' dataframe that counting the non-mising rows in column var1 by treatment group gives the following:

veh - 9
gr.4 - 8
gr.3 - 10
gr.2 - 5

But when using the sum(!is.na(x) I get the following

veh - 6
gr.4 - 5
gr.3 - 10
gr.2 - 5

I believe this is because the function is using both var1 and var2 to sum the number of non-missing. I do not know how to correct for this.

Best,

Jack

Comment: It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `data.table` approach:

**DATA**

The data you have is cumbersome to read into R - please use `dput()` etc. to make it easier for others:

```
> dput(dt)
structure(list(someting = c("503", "553", "599", "647", "695", 
"728", "760", "793", "826", "859", "907", "955", "1003", "1036", 
"1084", "1131", "1179", "1226", "1274", "1322", "1355", "1402", 
"1450", "1497", "1545"), treatment = c("gr.2", "gr.2", "gr.2", 
"gr.2", "gr.2", "gr.2", "gr.2", "gr.2", "gr.2", "gr.2", "gr.2", 
"gr.3", "gr.3", "gr.3", "gr.3", "gr.3", "gr.3", "gr.3", "gr.3", 
"gr.3", "gr.3", "gr.3", "gr.3", "gr.4", "gr.4"), var1 = c(8, 
NA, 3, 3, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 8, 8, 8, NA, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
NA, 8, 8, 8, 8, NA), var2 = c(8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 8L, 8L, 8L, NA, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, NA, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
NA)), .Names = c("someting", "treatment", "var1", "var2"), row.names = c(NA, 
-25L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

**CODE**

```
dt[, .(var1.n = sum(!is.na(var1)),
       var2.n = sum(!is.na(var1)), 
       var1.mean = mean(var1, na.rm = T), 
       var2.mean = mean(var2, na.rm = T)), 
   by = .(treatment)]
```

**OUTPUT**

```
      treatment var1.n var2.n var1.mean var2.mean
1:      gr.2      5      5         6         8
2:      gr.3     10     10         8         8
3:      gr.4      1      1         8         8
```

For some reason the "veh" entries weren't read in. Hence the output is slightly different but the principle ought to be clear.

Comment: The data I put was just an example, my actual data has about 40 variables. which is why I am trying to use aggregate and function(x). Your code would require me to create a separate line of code for n, mean, and sd which would be too cumbersome. My apologies for the cumbersome data- will use dput next time.

Comment: @Jbnimble You can refer to the answers posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11680579/assign-multiple-columns-using-in-data-table-by-group for multiple column assignments. A vector with new column names can be created using `lapply` on `colnames(dt)` and the values can be obtained from a function call or any of the other methods specified in the answers.